# labels of pie chart are strings

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have a series of pie chart to plot and the categories (labels) are strings. How can I still plot the pie charts even if the labels are strings and not integers?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Kanton': ['AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'AG', 'ZH', 'ZH', 'ZH', 'ZH', 'ZH', 'ZH'],
           'Kat': ['1b','4','5','6','1c','4','2a','3','3','3','2b','5','1d']})

kantone=df['Kanton'].unique()

for i in kantone:
   #print(i)
   df_n=df.loc[df['Kanton'] == i, 'Kat'].value_counts()

   #print(df_n)

   #define data
   data = df_n
   labels = df_n.index.values


   colors = sns.color_palette("bright", len(df['Kat'].unique()))


   #plot
   plt.pie(data, labels = labels, colors=[colors[k-1] for k in labels], autopct='%.0f%%')
   plt.title("Kanton " + i)
   plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
labels = df['Kat'].unique()
colors = sns.color_palette("bright", len(labels))
color_map = dict(zip(labels, colors))

for i in kantone:
   df_n = df.loc[df['Kanton'] == i, 'Kat'].value_counts()

   plt.pie(df_n, labels=df_n.index, colors=df_n.index.map(color_map), autopct='%.0f%%')
   plt.title("Kanton " + i)
   plt.show()
```

This code uses a color map to keep the same color for each label on all charts.

Output:

[image]

[image]